# Inserting data from an array of information?

Tags: php

I am not sure how to approach this, I need some advice on inserting data from a list of names. This is statistical type of data. Say I have an array that looks like this.

```
$basketball = array (
    'teams' => array (
        'orange' => array (
            'names'  => array(
                'matt' => array('number' => '12', 'position' => 'guard'), 
                'john' => array('number' => '23', 'position' => 'forward'),
            ),
        ),
        'blue' => array (
            'names'  => array(
                'luke' => array('number' => '34', 'position' => 'guard'), 
                'brian' => array('number' => '45', 'position' => 'forward'),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then inside my app I run a foreach on the names like this.

```
<?php foreach($basketball as $key => $teams): ?>
    <?php foreach($teams as $team => $names): ?>
    <div class="teams <?php echo $team ?>" data-score="0">
        <?php foreach($names as $key => $players): ?>
            <?php foreach($players as $player => $player_info): ?>
                <div class="home-stats stats <?php echo $team ?>" data-player="<?php echo $player ?>">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="name">
                        <span><?php echo $player ?></span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="home-playername" value="<?php echo $player ?>" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="points">
                        <span>0</span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="home-points" value="0" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With this I am trying to figure out the best approach for adding the data, so that points matches the player, obviously I will have more stats and players but for the sake of example this is all I need.

I was thinking of using `json` and rewriting the name attributes with jQuery and then building an array, and having a row for each team name, but again I can't think of how to rename these inputs to build a solid array, that looks like (sorry if Its a bit messed up but it's just an idea)

```
  {"players":[{"matt":[{"stats":[{"points":"22"}]}], 
               "john":[{"stats":[{"points":"18"}]}]}]}
```

I guess this may be a pretty broad question, but summed up given the information if you were the developer how would you approach statistical style of data, the name of the player being the parent of all the information... OR... possibly the team name being the parent of all the information, either way once I figure the best approach I can go either way..

Answer (score 2):

You should use a plugin like ember.js, angular.js or backbone.js. You should create a simple RESTful API to retreive the data from your server. To accomplish this task, proceed into three steps :

1- Put your data in a database
Make sure that all relation are well thought. Don't throw random information in your database. When I look at your example, it already seems like you have an issue with the way you organize your data. The names should be an attribute of an object, not the name of a key. Use the power of OOP.

2- Map your database into objects
Save yourself huge trouble and use doctrine. It helps you map data and relation between your entity. You could map your whole application with less then 50 lines of code.

3- Return the data
Return it in whatever format you need. JSON is very mainstream but you could decide to return XML or YAML. It's up to you. Use whatever you feel confortable with.

I personnaly use Ember.js. It uses [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for your template. In the end your code should be super short and clean:

```
<div id="comments">
    {{#each player}}
        <h2>#{{id}}">{{name}}</a></h2>
        <div>{{points}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

If you don't know how these frameworks works **take the time to learn them**. The way you're doing it right now is wrong. Take the best habit possible and learn how to build a solid application using MVC architecture.

Hope it helps

Comment: I appreciate this, I need to make a more OOP approach. I hear and see backbone, and ember alot. Never understood it fully. Let me soak all this up...

Comment: Yes I recently picked it up myself, and beleive me the time you take learning a framework is equal to the time you would waste making most of your functionnality manualy. Beleive me learning one of these framework will not only make you a better programmer, but it will also be a great time investment.

Comment: Yeah I keep hearing this, I also am going to use a PHP framework after this app like zend.